# How do I fix my VNC setup?

Tags: vnc, vncserver

I am using Real VNC Viewer on Mac OSX 10.6 and Tight VNC Server on Windows XP.

This setup was working.  I have not changed any settings to cause it not to work.  But now I am not receiving screen updates to the VNC viewer.  If I am controlling my Server from my Viewer in the same room.  I can see that I am moving the mouse and sending mouse-clicks.  But I am not receiving screen updates to the Viewer.

I have a VNC viewer on my iPhone.  If I use it to connect to my Server, it works fine.  So I figure the problem is with my VNC Viewer.  I have tried uninstalling it and reinstalling it but to no avail.  I do not know if there are any preferences that are being saved even with the uninstall?

Any ideas or points in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Why not test with the VNC viewer that is build into the Mac OS X?

Try --> Connect to Server --> vnc://*IP ADDRESS*

Now, I don't use it to connect to VNC, but to other Macintoshes, but I suspect that it will work with normal VNC servers...

Comment: Yes this works fine.